# MPI data type for 2D array

Tags: c++, mpi

For hours im trying to send 2D array over MPI to diffrent thread. Code looks like this (i'll leave comments to show tricks that i have already tryed):

Type definition:

```
// Define datatype
//MPI_Type_contiguous(N, MPI_INT, &mpi_vector);
//MPI_Type_vector(N, N, N, mpi_vector, &mpi_matrix);
//MPI_Type_vector(N, N, N, MPI_INT, &mpi_matrix);
//MPI_Type_contiguous(N, MPI_INTEGER, &mpi_vector);
//MPI_Type_contiguous(N, mpi_vector, &mpi_matrix);
MPI_Type_vector(N, N, 0, MPI_INTEGER, &mpi_matrix);
//MPI_Type_commit(&mpi_vector);
MPI_Type_commit(&mpi_matrix);
```

Sending and recieving:

```
int** tmp = new int*[N];
switch(r) {
case T1:
    inputMatrix(tmp, 2);
    MPI_Send(tmp, 1, mpi_matrix, T2, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    //task_T1();
    break;
case T2:
    //task_T2();
    inputMatrix(tmp, -1);
    MPI_Recv(tmp, 1, mpi_matrix, T1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &s);
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            cout << "  " << tmp[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    break;
}
```

I need to have this done till morning (in 7 hours), i hope smb is able to help me.

Comment: It gets a lot easier if you store your 2D array as a single array in row/column-major order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MPI **DOES NOT SUPPORT** matrices in which each row is allocated separately, a.k.a. array of pointers to rows. MPI works *only* with flat arrays where rows are stored consecutively in memory. Use a flat array:

```
int** tmp = ...
```

should become

```
int* tmp = new int[rows*cols];
```

and then `tmp[row][col]` should be accessed as `tmp[row*cols + col]`.

You can construct a contiguous type from `MPI_INT` for a single row and then construct a contiguous type from the previous contiguous type for the whole matrix. You can also construct a single contiguous type of `rows*cols` `MPI_INT` elements. The first approach is more flexible as you might need to send individual rows later.