# MPI_Send works only with statically allocated buffer

Tags: c, mpi

If I want to define my own type, and use it as a datatype with `MPI_Send` to take only even rows from a matrix, does that matrix (send buffer) have to be allocated statically?

I seem to have problems when I allocate it dynamically. Is this because addresses need to be successive for data to be sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, memory to be sent with `MPI_Send` does not have to be statically allocated.

To send array subsets, you likely want to use `MPI_Type_indexed`. Here is a slightly modified version of the example from the [mpi.deino.net article on `MPI_Type_indexed`](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Type_indexed.html), where I have replaced the statically allocated buffer

```
int buffer[27];
```

to a dynamically allocated buffer

```
int* buffer = (int*)malloc(27 * sizeof(int));
```

I hope it helps:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rank, size, i;
    MPI_Datatype type, type2;
    int blocklen[3] = { 2, 3, 1 };
    int displacement[3] = { 0, 3, 8 };
    int* buffer = (int*)malloc(27 * sizeof(int)); //int buffer[27];
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    if (size < 2)
    {
        printf("Please run with 2 processes.\n");
        MPI_Finalize();
        return 1;
    }
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    MPI_Type_contiguous(3, MPI_INT, &type2);
    MPI_Type_commit(&type2);
    MPI_Type_indexed(3, blocklen, displacement, type2, &type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&type);

    if (rank == 0)
    {
        for (i=0; i<27; i++)
            buffer[i] = i;
        MPI_Send(buffer, 1, type, 1, 123, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    if (rank == 1)
    {
        for (i=0; i<27; i++)
            buffer[i] = -1;
        MPI_Recv(buffer, 1, type, 0, 123, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        for (i=0; i<27; i++)
            printf("buffer[%d] = %d\n", i, buffer[i]);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Everything said here is correct, I'll just add that (as comes [up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576497/mpi-type-vector-does-not-seem-to-receive-send-what-it-should/17635444) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901476/sending-and-receiving-2d-array-over-mpi/5901671) [quite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883259/mpi-and-multidimensional-array-allocation-in-c/12883485) [often](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104847/mpi-bcast-a-dynamic-2d-array), you will likely need to make sure the multi-d array is contiguous in memory, even if the subsets you send aren't.

Comment: @niklasfi Ok, thank you for your answer, but I am interested in what happens with multidimensional array. I have probably formed the question poorly, but I wan't to know do I need to allocate memory for matrices statically, so they would be contiguous in memory, or can I do it dynamically?

Comment: @JonathanDursi that is what I'm interested in. So the problems appear if matrix elements aren't contiguous in memory?

Comment: @breakpoint - if they're noncontiguous in a predictable way - known slices of a larger data structure, say - then you're fine, and you can define an MPI data type to efficiently pull those out and put them into messages (and vice versa).  If they're noncontiguous in a  non-predictable way - you looped over malloc()s to build your array, say - then it's much more awkward, and you'll have to have a different MPI type for each _instance_ of the structure.  For technical computing, you normally want memory to be contiguous anyway for performance (cache) reasons.